# How do we remove particular object from js Map object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have some objects inside js Map object. How do we remove object with particular key and value?

```
let newMap = new Map()

newMap.set('1', {ep: '1', name: 'First test'})
newMap.set('2', {ep: '2', name: 'Second test'})
```

So, the above example holds two object inside newMap. How can I remove object with ep value '1', so that the newMap hash returns only one object i.e. `{ep: '2', name: 'Second test'}`.

Comment: Instead of setting item based on index, set it based on unique key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stored it under the key `'1'`. So you call [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete) with that key:

```
newMap.delete('1');
```

If you don't know the key you've stored it under, a `Map` probably isn't the structure you wanted, but you can find it by looping through [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), which returns an array whose entries are arraysin `[key, value]` format:

```
for (const entry of newMap.entries()) { // for-of is ES2015+
    if (entry[1].ep === '1') {
        newMap.delete(entry[0]);
        break;
    }
}
```

...or with ES5:

```
newMap.entries().some(function(entry) {
    if (entry[1].ep === '1') {
        newMap.delete(entry[0]);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate over the entries and `find` the object you want to remove, then `delete` the appropriate key:

```js
let newMap = new Map();
newMap.set('1', {ep: '1', name: 'First test'});
newMap.set('2', {ep: '2', name: 'Second test'});

const entryToRemove = [...newMap.entries()].find(([, { ep }]) => ep === '1');
newMap.delete(entryToRemove[0]);
console.log(newMap); // look in browser console, not snippet console
```

(Of course, if you can count on the map's key being the same as the `ep`, just do `newMap.delete(epToDelete)`)

Answer (score 0):

Your map looks like this:

> Map {   '1' => { ep: '1', name: 'First test' },   '2' => { ep: '2',
>   name: 'Second test' } }

To remove ep:'1' and have onlye ep:'2' you can try this:

```
newMap.delete('1');
```